# How to use Erlang file:read_file_info permissions/mode info?

Tags: file, permissions, erlang

The Erlang docs for `file:read_file_info/1` state "file permissions [are] the sum" and "other bits...may be set", not instilling confidence. And, Google has not been my friend here.

I'm looking to take the mode returned by `file:read_file_info/1`, e.g. `33188`, on a Linux machine and convert it into something more human readable and/or recognizable, like `rw-r--r--` or `644`.

Any tips, links, or directions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here's a starting point: stat -r "filename" will give you something like: "16777220 120436471 0100755 1 501 20 0 8 1351450865 1351450865 1351450865 1351450865 4096 8 0 foo" where the 3rd value is the file permissions in octal form.  Convert that to integer and you'll get the 33188 (or equivalent) value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short way:

```
io_lib:format("~.8B", [Mode]).
```

... or:

```
io_lib:format("~.8B", [Mode band 8#777]).
```

For `Mode = 33204` these two will give you respectively: `["100664"]` and `["664"]`.

The long way:

```
print(Mode) ->
    print(Mode band 8#777, []).

print(0, Acc) when length(Acc) =:= 9 ->
    Acc;
print(N, Acc) ->
    Char = perm(N band 1, length(Acc) rem 3),
    print(N bsr 1, [Char | Acc]).

perm(0, _) ->
    $-;
perm(1, 0) ->
    $x;
perm(1, 1) ->
    $w;
perm(1, 2) ->
    $r.
```

This one (function `print/1`) for `Mode = 33204` will give you this as result: `"rw-rw-r--"`.

---

If something was unclear for one, I'll try to expound basic things behind the snippets which I have provided.

As @macintux mentioned already, the `33204` in fact is a decimal representation of the octal number 100664. These three lowest octal digits (`664`) there is probably what you need, and so we get them with bitwise and (`band`) operation with the highest number which fits in three octal digits (`8#777`). That's why short way is so short - you just tell erlang to convert `Mode` to string as if it was the octal number.

The second representation you've mentioned (like `rw-rw-r--`, something that `ls` spits out) is easily reproducible from binary representation of the `Mode` number. Note that three octal digits will give you exactly nine binary digits (`8#644 = 2#110110100`). In fact this is the string `rwxrwxrwx` where each element replaced by `-` if corresponding digit equals `0`. If digit is `1` the element remains untouched.

So there is slightly cleaner approach to achieve this:

```
print(Mode) ->
    print(Mode band 8#777, lists:reverse("rwxrwxrwx"), []).

print(0, [], Acc) ->
    Acc;
print(N, [Char0 | Rest], Acc) ->
    Char = char(N band 1, Char0),
    print(N bsr 1, Rest, [Char | Acc]).

char(0, _) ->
    $-;
char(1, C) ->
    C.
```

---

I hope you got the point. Anyway feel free to ask any questions in comments if you doubt.