# Can NOT list_dir in Documents\My Pictures in erlang on windows 7

Tags: erlang

I've started erlang shell as windows administrator, but file:list_dir return {error,eacces}:

```
 15> cd("My Pictures").
     c:/Users/t450/Documents/My Pictures
     ok
 16> file:list_dir(".").
     {error,eacces}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know why {error,eacces} returned

It sounds like the administrator does not have read permissions for the directory `c:/Users/t450/Documents/My Pictures`.  An administrator does not have permissions for every directory. For why an administrator may not have permissions to read the My Pictures directory see [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/930128/error-message-when-you-try-to-access-the-my-documents--my-music--my-pi) and [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/16b604f7-75fe-41e0-81cd-303b43ed32a5/cannot-access-folders-and-files-even-with-administrator-rights?forum=w7itprosecurity).  I suggest you [examine the permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx) for the My Pictures directory.  You can also [examine the permissions programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183838/how-to-use-erlang-fileread-file-info-permissions-mode-info) with `file:read_file_info()`.